# Kubernetes and Istio dynamic port mapping

Tags: kubernetes, istio

It there a way to use some kind of dynamic port mapping in the following scenario
(Istio > Kubernetes service):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
    # my-service.default.svc.cluster.local ?
  - "*"
  gateways: 
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /somepath/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-service
```

And when using Istio, the end user do not need to know the port, and therefore is possible to create and use a dynamic free port?

```
Defining a service:
# K8s - Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: my-port
    port: #***  Dynamic port? ***#
    targetPort: 80
```

Comment: What do you mean "dynamic port mapping"?

Comment: So I dont need to define a port number, as Istio just uses host name

Comment: Check [this](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#Destination) link for using Istio `VirtualService` and Service [types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) in Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks, but I did read this :-) Do you know how it it is possible to have some kind of dynamic lookup?

Comment: Haven't heard that it can be possible to achieve.